# Properly encoding text in the bulk uploader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, character-encoding, bulkloader

What is the proper way to encode strings for the bulk uploader. It is currently bailing out when it runs into an apostrophe inside my text fields.

Here's a sample CSV file:

```
demo,name,message
FALSE,one,"Welcome message"
FALSE,two,"If you’re having a medical emergency"
```

Here's my bulkloader.yaml:

```
transformers:
- kind: Message
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
   encoding: utf-8
   columns: from_header
  property_map:
   - property: demo
     external_name: demo
     import_transform: bool
   - property: name
     external_name: name
     import_transform: str
   - property: message
     external_name: message
     import_transform: str
```

When I run the loader with a sample like this (that has apostrophes in the text), I'll get the following error...

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position x: ordinal not in range(128)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`’` isn't an ASCII character. You should try changing the property transform to be `import_transform: unicode`